# Class Or Object?

Tags: typescript

In the Angular official tutorial they have an example of a simple class (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1) and they use the class like an object, which I don't understand.

```
class Hero{
     id: number;
     name: string
```

and it's used like this...

```
const HEROES: Hero[] = [
       { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
       { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
       { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
       { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
    ];
```

and this is used as a list in the HTML. (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2)

Being new to Typescript, I simply don't understand how this is done. In Python for ex. the only way to use a Class is to instantiate it. I know objects can be created and used like this in Javascript, but to my knowledge not using the class keyword.

I've googled this, watched vids on Typescript, and cannot find anyone else doing something similar. If someone could point me to documentation I would appreciate it greatly! Or, just a simple explanation with ex.

Comment: It should be  `id: number;` and `name: string;`. Without the `'`; see the linked [example](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#create-a-hero-class).

Comment: Gotcha, my fault.

Comment: You could `new` up an instance, but then you'd need to write a constructor and TSC really only cares if objects meet the right interfaces. In this example there's no need for it to be a class; it *could* just be an interface.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought as far as it could be an interface. But, they used a class, and I didn't know you could just use a class this way. I don't understand how this works, is there documentation on using a class this way? If it was just an object (in J.S.) I'd understand, but it's a class. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Yes I understand what's happening, but not how. In say Python, if you make a class, it has to be instantiated before any data can be used. There is no installation here, so how does this work?

Comment: Or I suppose it is being instantiated, Michael. Just all using the same var, Hero. Is that correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a dynamic object valid to set to a class in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579148/why-is-a-dynamic-object-valid-to-set-to-a-class-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a look at the documentation.

> Define a HEROES constant as an array of ten heroes.

Do you understand what is going on here? We take an array of ids and names and we are assigning that to an array of hero elements. A single element version would be like the following:

```
const HERO: Hero = { id:21, name: 'myName'};
```

It's very struct-like in nature, but testing [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) shows you its just turns into `var HERO = { id: 50, name: 'test' };`. There are other ways to get immutability for an object but syntactically they are a nightmare, but that's neither here nor there. This was merely a way to shorthand the instantiation into one "line" (i.e. before a semicolon).

Comment: Yes, I understand what's happening, but I was unsure how because it looked as if the class wasn't being instantiated. Now looking at it closer, I suppose it is, just all using the same variable 'Hero'. . .Am I correct on that assumption?

Comment: Looking at your ex, it looks as if a class in TSC is basically an object?

Comment: In Python if a class is used, it must be instaniated such as superman = Hero(id=1, name=Clark). In this case, the class isn't used like this, it's basically used like an object from what I understand. . .I'm not used to JS or TSC, other than DOM manipulation.

Comment: I know it can be difficult to learn other programming languages that have almost a cryptic case of syntax sometimes (I just started learning Lisp myself and felt this way when I started learning php). An Object is an instantiation of a class, but in javascript this functionality is lacking, which is why we have things like typescript to transpile for us. AFAIK, the HEROES array and Hero class are unrelated in plain js, but ts can provide for us an interface for interactions.

Comment: In javascript, the equivalent code looks like this:
`var Hero = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Hero() {
    }
    return Hero;
}());
var HEROES = [{id:1, name:'test'},{id:2, name:'test'}];`
As you can see there really isn't much going on here

Comment: I think I see. I know there's very little going on, but I wanted to make sure I grasped fully what's happening. Looking at the JS it's compiled to, I believe I get it now. It's just weird, coming from a Python background. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to help! Yeah on the js side it doesn’t really do much, it’s more so up to the programmer to implement functionality. On a side note, if you aren’t in any hurry I always recommend learning the js side of things. It can be helpful to learn DOM Manipulation  and the like “the hard way”, so that you really further you understanding and can use transpiled languages to expedite your programming. I’ve found that often times the tools that make our jobs easier (IDEs, debuggers, frameworks, etc.) can dumb us down by taking power away from us and prevent a much needed failure. Good luck!

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is more or less just basic JavaScript. `{}` instantiates an object in JavaScript, and `{ id: 5 }` instantiates an object and gives it an `'id'` field with the value `5`.

Additionally, JavaScript has "duck typing", so to match "type" with a class you just need to share the same members. There's no actual "type". TypeScript introduces type checking, but the underlying object still has no intrinsic type.

Also TypeScript has lots of type inference, so it can see that the members match and will infer that they should be of type `Hero`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this very confusing as well. Once you use the `class` keyword, I think it makes more sense to use `new` to create instances as well.

It's not just 'syntactic sugar', it's also about defining a workflow.

If you prefer the Javascript syntax for working with objects, Typescript provides a way to define a Type for an object:

```
type Hero = { id: number, name: string }

const Heroes: Hero[] = [
    {id:3, name:"henk"}
]
```